# React scroll div have props element Cannot read properties of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

**This is my code. I got error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'scrollIntoView')" because I props element render after code shows in the browser. I need to fix it with a dynamic way without manually**

How to make props element render before the code shows in the browser so that I can click in the button and scroll?

```
import { useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import {data} from '../clients'
import Coffee from '../img/coffee.png'
import Client from './Client';


export default function Reviews() {
    const [scroll, setScroll] = useState('client1');

    useEffect(() => {
        document.getElementById(scroll).scrollIntoView()
    }, [scroll])

    const handleScroll = (e) => {
        setScroll(e);
    }

    return (
        <div id="reviews" className="h-screen overflow-hidden w-full bg-[#A75E35] relative">
            <div className="bg-[#653114] opacity-30 absolute h-1/2 w-1/4 blur-3xl top-0 right-[-5%] rounded-full"></div>
            <div className="bg-[#653114] opacity-30 absolute h-2/3 w-1/4 blur-3xl bottom-20 left-[-5%] rounded-full"></div>
            <div className=" w-full h-full flex justify-center items-center">
                <img className='md:h-[738px] md:w-[895px] md:scale-[65%] scale-75 opacity-25' src={Coffee} alt="coffee" />
            </div>
            <div className='h-full w-full absolute flex md:flex-row flex-col items-center justify-center top-0'>
                <div className='py-2 md:py-0 md:h-3/4 w-4/5 lg:w-4/6 overflow-hidden'>
                    {data.map(e => <Client key={e.id} id={e.id} information = {{name: e.name, pic: e.pic, par: e.par, direction: e.direction, startsnum: e.startsnum}} />
                    )}
                </div>
                <div className='md:h-3/4 md:w-16 w-4/5 h-16 flex md:flex-col space-x-4 md:space-x-0 md:space-y-4 justify-center items-center'>
                    {data.map(e => <div key={e.id} onClick={() => handleScroll(e.id)} className={`${scroll === e.id ? "bg-[#653114]" : "bg-[#D9D9D9] duration-300 ease-in-out hover:bg-[#8d451e] cursor-pointer"} w-4 h-4 rounded-full`}></div>)}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Anytime you call `document.*` in React code you should stop and consider that you might be doing something wrong (not all cases, but often). Instead of using an `id` you should instead be using a [`ref`](https://react.dev/learn/referencing-values-with-refs). This will allow you to both access the element _and_ determine when it has rendered